# Websphere - developing on liberty, deployment on WAS V8.5.5

Tags: websphere

I'm developing application for WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.
But there is only trial - 60 days. 
Websphere Liberty is free.
If I will be developing my application on Liberty, it will be fine on normal Application Server?
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this for small applications, and had success. When you use Java EE APIs and their related Liberty features, you have to make sure you stick to only the [Java EE 6 versions of those features](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_prog_model_support_javaee6.html) if you want to maintain full compatibility since that's all WebSphere 8.5.5 supports. There are even some features, like the ones that implement MicroProfile APIs, that only exist for Liberty, not WebSphere.

You should also make sure you run the development server on the same Java SE version you'll deploy on, so you don't try to deploy an app with Java 8 language features on a Java 7-based WebSphere install.

Comment: (In case it helps at all, I wrote a bit about my use of a subset of Liberty for my tWAS application here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/Liberty_for_a_Traditionalist )

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes", you can develop on Liberty and deploy on traditional WAS, as long as you use Liberty features that are supported on traditional WAS (eg. currently Java EE 8 is not supported on traditional WAS).

Note that both WebSphere Liberty and "traditional" WebSphere Application Server, v8.5.5 and v9.0, are free for development use (defined as 1 developer on a physical or virtual "developer machine"). Check out this blog:

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/WAS_traditional_for_Developers

For v8.5.5, there was a free to download "WebSphere Application Server for Developers" offering. For v9.0, we changed the license so the separate Developers offering is no longer needed.

The v8.5.5 developer use is summarized in the v8.5.5 announcement letter (from way back in 2013):

http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&appname=gpateam&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS213-137

Now you can get WebSphere Application Server, and the corresponding tools needed to create and develop applications, fully supported on the developer desktop as part of your WebSphere Application Server support. Customers with an active support contract for their production WebSphere Application Server are allowed to install the same WebSphere Application Server edition onto developer machines for use in development and testing. These installations of WebSphere Application Server, as well as the free to download WebSphere Application Server for Developers and WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse, are entitled for support on the developer machine as long as an active support contract is in place for the production server. This applies to WebSphere Application Server V8.5 and later.

Answer (score 0):

We do it like this in our company: we develop application on Liberty/Tomcat, while we run tests and production on traditional WAS.
Most of the time it works fine:
Developers like simplicity and speed of Liberty or even Tomcat, while admins and ops like the admin console and its plentiful of settings and tuning settings and monitoring.

You should however be warned, that Traditional Websphere in production limits your developers liberty: To run our application in "traditional WAS" we had to delete several jars from our application, and use their Websphere's versions instead.

Sometimes application that works in Liberty/Tomcat doesn't work out of the box in traditional WAS: surprises happen to us from time to time.

I am a supporter of moving not only development but also production into Liberty. For me Liberty and traditional WAS are like Edge and Internet Explorer browsers - the latter is limited by its backward compatibility requirements and long history, while the former is the future.